# angular & apache - $scope updated but need to click somewhere to show on interface

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, linux, apache

My project back-end wrote with PHP, front-end with Angular.js and server is running by Apache in Linux.
The problem is, anytime i want to redirect to new page like `$location.path("/home")` i have to click somewhere on body to affect!
Or sometimes on getting data from ajx GET or POST method, $scope updated but nothing show until clicking somewhere on body!

This is Routing Config:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', 
    function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
        .when('/home', {
            templateUrl: 'views/home/home.html',
            controller: 'homeControllers',
            caseInsensitiveMatch : true
        })
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'views/home/home.html',
            controller: 'homeControllers'
        })
        .otherwise('/')
        ;
    }
]);
```

This is my POST Service:

```
app.factory("method", function(primaries) {
    return {
        POST: function(url, obj, callBack) {
            $.ajax({
                url: primaries.urls.baseUrl + url,
                method: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: obj,
                success: function(data) {
                    if (callBack) {
                        return callBack(data);
                    }
                    return data;
                },
                error: function(data) {
                    //console.log('ERROR on ' + url);
                },
            });
        }
    }     
});
```

And this is how i fill my $scope:

```
method.POST("/est/view", {"test":"test"}, function(data) {
    $scope.param = data;
})
```

By the way, i tried `$scope.$apply()` but nothing changed!
I didn't have these problems on Localhost in windows with local data.
Whats the problem!?

Comment: Can you provide your routing code?

Comment: @AlbertoI.N.J. Done.

Answer (score 0):

Some of this issues most likely stem from the fact that you are using jQuery's `$.ajax` rather than Angular's `$http.post`.  If you **really** want to use jQuery's version, it is doable, but probably not worth the effort.

Change your code to this:

```
app.factory("method", function($http, primaries) {
    return {
        POST: function(url, obj) {
            return $http.post(url, obj);
        }
    }     
});
```

And then in your controller:

```
method.POST("/est/view", {"test":"test"}).then(function(data) {
    $scope.param = data;
});
```

One caveat is that PHP doesn't do to well with reading `POST` data sent as `JSON`, so you'll need to either make Angular send as form data, or read the JSON POST data with something like this:

```
$_JSON = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
if (!empty($_JSON)) {
    $_POST = $_JSON;
}
```